# The program [#####] iexplore.exe' has exited with code -########## The program '[#####] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis

I have asp.net MVC 3 application with extJs 4.0.7 as front end,which I used to run on VS 2015 professional and Windows 10. Whenever I am trying to execute that application it suddenly stops and throws an error: 
The program '[25076] iexplore.exe' has exited with code -1073741790 (0xc0000022).
The program '[23176] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

I used to run on Internet Explorer 11 (11.3630.14393.0). However it runs on chrome without such error.

*One way to run is run on chrome first-> copy the localhost url -> paste and run on IE, but doing this I can't debug the code.*

I googled/searched on the stack overflow and tried below solutions to fix it

1. Clean/Build/Rebuild the solution.
2. Restart the System
3. Reinstall visual studio 2015 professional
4. Deleted the .vs folder from the solution.
5. Changed the following option in Tools-> options -> projects and solutions
   [image]
6. Changed the following virtual directory and port number.
   [image]
7. Taken the latest checkout of the code.

**None of this solves the problem permanently. Sometimes it won't run for the entire day. And it gets fixed automatically on the next day. And this gets repeated after every random interval.**

Comment: you must run all on 64bit - windows, the compilation, the pools, the libraries... all under 64bit - you have miss something

Comment: Could you find more exception in event viewer?

Comment: @JokiesDing - No there is no any error in event viewer